# Optional (repeated) field in proto 3

Tags: protocol-buffers

I use protobuf and the `proto 3` syntax to define messages.

I want to be able to make a distinction between fields when their values weren't provided (unspecified) and when their values were set/left with their default values (`0` for int32, `[]` for repeated, etc).
For values, there are well known wrapper which allows that, but for custom messages one's on his own.

Some people came up with a technique relying on oneof, but it doesn't work with collections (repeated or maps).

Now I'm starting to consider just systematically writing wrappers for each message.

```
message MyMessage {
  int32 id = 1;
  string name = 2;
  // ...
  message Optional {
    MyMessage value = 1;
  }
  message OptionalRepeated {
    repeated MyMessage values = 1;
  }    
}
```

Even if `MyMessage.OptionalRepeated` or  `MyMessage.Optional` might never be used.

I guess people must have come to rely on such pattern, so maybe there's already a tool that can auto generate this boilerplate code.
Do you know a tool to lessen this burden? Or even better, is there  a better approach?

Answer (score -1):

In many cases, it may be better to explicitly convey the meaning that you are trying to implicitly convey by the optional fields.

Often it can be just a separate `bool` field. Consider for example:

```
message UpdateParameters
{
   bool updateServerList = 1;
   repeated ServerType serverList = 2;
}
```

This makes it clear to whoever reads the code that if you want to update to `[]`, you'll just set `updateServerList = true` and `serverList = []`. If it were a single field of type `optionalServerList`, it's not as clear what will happen if the parameter is just missing, and on the other hand without extra comments the distinction between empty and missing could be lost on whoever implements the other side of the protocol.

Having a separate field also offers more possibilities for compatibility-retaining updates. You might for example add `Timestamp updateIfOlderThan = 3;` while still retaining possibility to separately define behaviour for old clients that only know of `true/false` field.

Answer (score -1):

You can user [google.protobuf.ListValue](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/google.protobuf#listvalue)

https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/master/src/google/protobuf/struct.proto